# Ejecutar Timer una sola vez

Tags: c#

Tengo un Forms con una conexion a una base de datos llamada CONN, quiero agregar a mi forms un timer, el cual cuando yo ejecute el forms el timer se ejecute y si no encuentra la conexion con el servidor este me mande un mensaje de perdida de conexion, pero que este mensaje sea solo uno no mas.
Ayuda!!

Este es parte de mi codigo.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexion.getConexion());

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha perdido la conexion", "Registro de Clientes VIP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes detener el timer usando el `Stop()`

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexion.getConexion());

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();

    if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        MessageBox.Show("Se ha perdido la conexion", "Registro de Clientes VIP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

}
```

[Timer.Stop Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.stop?view=netframework-4.5)

AL realizarse el evento se detiene el timer, ejecutando solo esa vez

Comment: Tengo un error aunque tenga la conexion (el sql server con la conexion abierta)  la esta viendo como cerrada. como hago para que realmente detecte cuando no hay conexion?

Comment: sino realizaste el `conn.Open()` va a estar cerrada

Comment: muchisimas gracias!